# Why is my json response not conforming to my struct?

Tags: ios, json, swift, apiary.io

I have made a simple api to test on apiary, I have created a struct for the response. But when the call is made and I try to make it conform to my struct for some reason I do not get the body and only get the header. I would like to get the little league teams and place them into this struct and then print them.

API link:
https://littleleaguers.docs.apiary.io/#reference/0/little-league-teams/list-all-little-league-teams

Response Body:

```
 {
    "name": "Little League Teams"
    "teams": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "team": "Yankees",
            "players": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "position": 1,
                    "player": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "position": 2,
                    "player": {
                        "name": "John",
                        "last": "Johnson",
                        "jersey": 5
                        "signed_up": "2018-07-16T08:40:51.620Z"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "position": 3,
                    "player": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "position": 4,
                    "player": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "position": 5,
                    "player": {
                        "name": "Blake",
                        "last": "Smith",
                        "jersey": 28
                        "signed_up": "2018-07-14T18:23:23.000Z"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "position": 6,
                    "player": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 7,
                    "position": 7,
                    "player": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 8,
                    "position": 8,
                    "player": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 9,
                    "position": 9,
                    "player": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 10,
                    "position": 10,
                    "player": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 11,
                    "position": 11,
                    "player": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 12,
                    "position": 12,
                    "player": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "team": "Red Sox",
            "players": [
                {
                    "id": 13,
                    "position": 1,
                    "player": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 14,
                    "position": 2,
                    "player": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 15,
                    "position": 3,
                    "player": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 16,
                    "position": 4,
                    "player": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 17,
                    "position": 5,
                    "player": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 18,
                    "position": 6,
                    "player": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 19,
                    "position": 7,
                    "player": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

League.swift:

```
struct League: Decodable {
var name: String
var  teams: [Teams]
```

}

Team.swift:

```
    struct Team: Decodable {
var id: Int
var team: String
var players: [Players]

}
```

Players.swift:

```
 struct Players: Decodable {

var id: Int
var position: Int
var player: player?

}

    struct player: Decodable {

var name: String
var last: String
var jersey: Int
var signed_up: String

}
```

I then have a class to retrieve this data:

GetData.swift:

```
    class GetData{
    func getLeague(){
        let url = URL(string: "https://private-4df2e8-littleleaguers.apiary-mock.com/league")!
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
      if let response = response {
        print("RESPONSE \(response)")

       /* if let data = data, let body = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
          print("BODY \(body)")
          // this line prints the body
        }*/
        if let data = data, let dataObtained = try? JSONDecoder().decode(League.self, from: data){

            print("DATA \(dataObtained).....")// this line does not print 
        }
      } else {
        print(error ?? "Unknown error")
      }
    }

    task.resume()
    }

 }
```

I then call this in ViewController.swift by:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let getData = GetData()
    getData.getLeague()
}
```

The only thing that prints in the console is:

```
 RESPONSE <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x6000008e5e80> { URL: https://private-4df2e8-littleleaguers.apiary-mock.com/league } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" =     (
        "*"
    );
    "Content-Encoding" =     (
        gzip
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        427
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Fri, 06 Mar 2020 13:35:40 GMT"
    );
    Vary =     (
        "Accept-Encoding"
    );
    "access-control-allow-methods" =     (
        "OPTIONS,GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,DELETE,TRACE,CONNECT"
    );
    "access-control-max-age" =     (
        10
    );
    "x-apiary-ratelimit-limit" =     (
        120
    );
    "x-apiary-ratelimit-remaining" =     (
        119
    );
    "x-apiary-transaction-id" =     (
        5e6251ac6b105b008135d67a
    );
} }
```

Comment: Don't `try?`, remove the question mark and **`catch`** the `Decoding` error.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid, it's missing commas after some of the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing a bit the JSON that comes back, which is wrong, everything in your struct models is fine check this out on [online swift playground](http://online.swiftplayground.run):

```
import Foundation

let json = """
 {
    "name": "Little League Teams",
    "teams": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "team": "Yankees",
            "players": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "position": 1,
                    "player": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "position": 2,
                    "player": {
                        "name": "John",
                        "last": "Johnson",
                        "jersey": 5,
                        "signed_up": "2018-07-16T08:40:51.620Z"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "position": 3,
                    "player": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "position": 4,
                    "player": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "position": 5,
                    "player": {
                        "name": "Blake",
                        "last": "Smith",
                        "jersey": 28,
                        "signed_up": "2018-07-14T18:23:23.000Z"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "position": 6,
                    "player": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 7,
                    "position": 7,
                    "player": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 8,
                    "position": 8,
                    "player": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 9,
                    "position": 9,
                    "player": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 10,
                    "position": 10,
                    "player": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 11,
                    "position": 11,
                    "player": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 12,
                    "position": 12,
                    "player": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "team": "Red Sox",
            "players": [
                {
                    "id": 13,
                    "position": 1,
                    "player": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 14,
                    "position": 2,
                    "player": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 15,
                    "position": 3,
                    "player": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 16,
                    "position": 4,
                    "player": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 17,
                    "position": 5,
                    "player": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 18,
                    "position": 6,
                    "player": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 19,
                    "position": 7,
                    "player": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct player: Decodable {
    var name: String
    var last: String
    var jersey: Int
    var signed_up: String
}

struct Players: Decodable {
    var id: Int
    var position: Int
    var player: player?
}

struct Team: Decodable {
    var id: Int
    var team: String
    var players: [Players]
}

struct League: Decodable {
    var name: String
    var teams: [Team]
}


if let results = try? JSONDecoder().decode(League.self, from: json) {
    print(results)
}
```

Output:

> League(name: "Little League Teams", teams: [SwiftPlayground.Team(id:
>   1, team: "Yankees", players: [SwiftPlayground.Players(id: 1, position:
>   1, player: nil), SwiftPlayground.Players(id: 2, position: 2, player:
>   Optional(SwiftPlayground.player(name: "John", last: "Johnson", jersey:
>   5, signed_up: "2018-07-16T08:40:51.620Z"))),
>   SwiftPlayground.Players(id: 3, position: 3, player: nil),
>   SwiftPlayground.Players(id: 4, position: 4, player: nil),
>   SwiftPlayground.Players(id: 5, position: 5, player:
>   Optional(SwiftPlayground.player(name: "Blake", last: "Smith", jersey:
>   28, signed_up: "2018-07-14T18:23:23.000Z"))),
>   SwiftPlayground.Players(id: 6, position: 6, player: nil),
>   SwiftPlayground.Players(id: 7, position: 7, player: nil),
>   SwiftPlayground.Players(id: 8, position: 8, player: nil),
>   SwiftPlayground.Players(id: 9, position: 9, player: nil),
>   SwiftPlayground.Players(id: 10, position: 10, player: nil),
>   SwiftPlayground.Players(id: 11, position: 11, player: nil),
>   SwiftPlayground.Players(id: 12, position: 12, player: nil)]),
>   SwiftPlayground.Team(id: 2, team: "Red Sox", players:
>   [SwiftPlayground.Players(id: 13, position: 1, player: nil),
>   SwiftPlayground.Players(id: 14, position: 2, player: nil),
>   SwiftPlayground.Players(id: 15, position: 3, player: nil),
>   SwiftPlayground.Players(id: 16, position: 4, player: nil),
>   SwiftPlayground.Players(id: 17, position: 5, player: nil),
>   SwiftPlayground.Players(id: 18, position: 6, player: nil),
>   SwiftPlayground.Players(id: 19, position: 7, player: nil)])])